# Mapped types: Make property required based on whether array of same object contains string literal

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is it possible to make an object property dependent on whether an array of the same object contains a string literal?

```
type Operator = "A" |  "B"
type SomeStruct = {
    operators: Operator[];
    someProp: string; // this should be required if operators include "A", optional if not
}

// desired result
const structWithA: SomeStruct = {
  operators: ["A", "B"],
  someProp: "" // correct, since operators contains "A", someProp is required
};

const structWithB: SomeStruct = {
  operators: ["B"],
  // currently errors, but desired outcome is that it should not error, since operators does not contain "A"
};

declare const structs: SomeStruct[];

structs.map(struct => {
  if(struct.operators.includes("A")) {
    // someProp is safely accessible
  }

  // since .includes has a narrow type signature, maybe another way to safely access someProp is needed 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying a generic to `SomeStruct` (and using a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to discriminate its type), you can accomplish this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkMkG4BQpJQEIOV3S3GgHlIAnAQ2AHtKC4AfPTEnAZToFsJPglAK4BjYAB4yUCAA9gEAHYATAM5QKEGvUoA+AgG8odKrQYqAXOoDaAXSgBfKADIoACgxQoAJQgiGS8SQVXggABUpjJAAaKBVBAEsFAHM9WXllNUSAM00oABUoAH4PT1hpOUVVdSL8qEtQ6kpgeOoAG3E8nRLPSyEFAGsFOgB3BQwASnY-BTjYgEZLbj4BYTFJE209RENjTVNKCygrJCIYlCQbGOC+cONLJCQHTGnZlQAmRZCV0QkNLQYtlAdhszJZjqdkKg7PY0FAAPRwqAAUUoEUYrjeAGY3m9xhgXsBYpjPstBD9xDBAcC9tpDscoVcQrcwPdHjD8XQZoSVAAWEn8MlrSkGIwgg5g87Q2EI5GohhuLE4vEE2IAVn53zWuCpoppoKOJwuTw5XNiADYNYKJNqRbt-uKDURLrEmREWcg2c9Oa8AOyW1YSYXbXX2ulS+GIlFohXY3Em14ADn95KDQJD+zDjJubtZxpVKgAnMmtTq7Rmwc7rmEcx6897uXMAAzF62lsWZl3Zu619kYJS+VqNaD5q2HVxLAUB9Z63TjWzsLJ9MTxTlQRIiVpCfsqOCuOIBlvT+06caWfc-NdqCeawN6fQlSgQYBCSgKWJWgB0ZdpH-Xm+3rjnJMGD2BgGDnmIKgfjw1BgHuVoIHeJTxFkrh-luEA7vBAbjOMQLdO+AYflWzLSoi+6JEkJSgfYkxAA)

```ts
type A = 'A';
type B = 'B';
type Operator = A | B;

type SomeStruct<O extends Operator> = { operators: O[] } & (
  Record<'someProp', string> extends infer T ?
    A extends O ? T : Partial<T>
    : unknown
);

const s1: SomeStruct<Operator> = { operators: ['B', 'A'], someProp: '' };
const s2: SomeStruct<Operator> = { operators: ['B', 'A'] }; // Error (2322)
const s3: SomeStruct<A> = { operators: ['A'], someProp: '' };
const s4: SomeStruct<A> = { operators: ['A'] }; // Error (2322)
const s5: SomeStruct<B> = { operators: ['B'] };
const s6: SomeStruct<B> = { operators: ['B'], someProp: '' };
const s7: SomeStruct<A> = { operators: [] }; // Error (2322)
const s8: SomeStruct<A> = { operators: [], someProp: '' };
const s9: SomeStruct<B> = { operators: [], someProp: '' };
const s10: SomeStruct<B> = { operators: [], someProp: '' };

declare const structs: (SomeStruct<Operator>)[];

function includesA (struct: SomeStruct<Operator>): struct is SomeStruct<A> {
  return struct.operators.includes('A');
}

structs.map(struct => {
  if(includesA(struct)) {
    struct.someProp; // string
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would allow `const structWithB = craeteStruct({ operators: ["B", "A"] });` without raising an error

Comment: @floriannorbertbepunkt You're right. I've updated my answer. Sorry the first version didn't work (and that the updated version isn't as ergonomic).

Comment: Thanks. I think the main inconvenience is that this does not scale very well, e. g. if you have five operators, all with their own additional props. Basically we would need a way to express array contains X as a discriminator